# Statistics for Meteor App

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flow-router

I have built an e-commerce Meteor app and now I want to have some stats of how people interacting with my site, which routes the visit and so on.

The standart case is to apply GA to my site? Or may be any more suitable services exist ?and the main question is: are there any packages, that just collect internal meteor information (like changing routes and so on) ?

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package: https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics. It worked great for me before.